# drop down resets to first choice on some boxes but not others

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a long .php form (3320 lines). I have many  fields. When I click 
submit, and go through my error check, some fields retain their value and others reset to the first  value.

All the syntax is consistent. I remove the error checking and no difference.

This is an example of successful code:

```
<select name="Marital"  id="Marital" value="<?=$marital;?>">
    <option value="Single"<?= $_REQUEST["Marital"]== "Single"?" selected='selected'":""?>>Single</option>
    <option value="Married"<?= $_REQUEST["Marital"]== "Married"?" selected='selected'":""?>>Married</option>
    <option value="Divorced"<?= $_REQUEST["Marital"]== "Divorced"?" selected='selected'":""?>>Divorced</option>
    <option value="Widowed"<?= $_REQUEST["Marital"]== "Widowed"?" selected='selected'":""?>>Widowed</option>
</select>
```

This is an example of unsuccessful code:

```
<select name="Networth" id="Networth" value="<?=$net_worth;?>">
    <option value="0"<?= $_REQUEST["NetWorth"]== "0"?" selected='selected'":""?>>0</option>
    <option value="1"<?= $_REQUEST["NetWorth"]== "1"?" selected='selected'":""?>>1</option>
    <option value="2"<?= $_REQUEST["NetWorth"]== "2"?" selected='selected'":""?>>2</option>
    <option value="3"<?= $_REQUEST["NetWorth"]== "3"?" selected='selected'":""?>>3</option>
    <option value="4"<?= $_REQUEST["NetWorth"]== "4"?" selected='selected'":""?>>4</option>
    <option value="5"<?= $_REQUEST["NetWorth"]== "5"?" selected='selected'":""?>>5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You must be careful when comparing strings to numbers

Comment: `<?php echo` is  a ***whole*** lot more portable than `<?=`

Comment: I hadn't tried echo. I'll keep it for next time.  Thank you @FKEinternet

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to be strings / and numbers like you said Mr. Ken. 
I then found out (in another problem I would have posted later) that php does not like currency signs such as $, €, € ,    € , or €

Thanks.